# Android ArrayList Calendar add and get is different

Tags: java, android, arraylist, calendar, addition

I put increment date of the calendar and add into arraylist, but when i loop them out, the date is all same.

```
Calendar a = Calendar.getInstance();
ArrayList<Calendar> b = new ArrayList<Calendar>();

for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    a.add(Calendar.DATE, i>0 ? 1 : 0);
    b.add(a);
}

for (int i=0; i<b.size(); i++){
    Log.d("xxx", "test=" + b.get(i));
}
```

suppose i wan 10/11/2012, 11/11/2012, 12/11/2012

but it come out like 12/11/2012, 12/11/2012, 12/11/2012

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: the problem still the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding the same instance of `Calendar` to your `ArrayList` so when you go to print it out all the dates will be the same.

One solution would be to clone your `Calendar` objects, giving you different date values:

```
for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    a.add(Calendar.DATE, i > 0 ? 1 : 0);
    b.add(a);
    a = (Calendar)a.clone();
}
```

Consider instead, storing the dates as strings here though as this would be less of an overhead rather than creating multiple `Calendar` objects.

Answer (score 1):

the most memory optimized approach could be - push Strings in the array list by pushing `a.toString()`.

And then recreate them by using `SimpleDateFormatter` whenever needed.